# Silverman AEC 11b

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Some search on the internet and this site didn't result in any topic about this question of Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*:

Let $W \subset \mathbb{P^n}$ be a smooth algebraic set, each of whose component varieties has dimension $n-1$.
Prove that W is a variety.

hint: use Krull's Hauptidealsatz to show W is the zeroset of a single homogenous polynomial.

my ideas:
So if $I(V)$ contains at least two linear independent polynomials, 
we have to prove the height of $I(V)$ is at least $2$.

After that, it is enough to find one singular point, where we assume $I(V)=fg$ with $f,g$ nonconstant polynomials.

Comment: Could you explicit the letters AEC ? It should be a title, I imagine ? Let me guess ? Algebra Electronic Course ? Alternating Electric Current ?

Comment: It's Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves".

Answer (score 1):

If $W$ contains more than one component, then it is the union of projective subvarieties of codimension 1, which necessarily have non-empty intersection. (This is immediate from Bezout but if you prefer a smaller hammer, also follows from the Krull height theorem.) Then, we need to check that $W$ cannot possibly be smooth at a point lying on two or more of these components. We can work affine-locally and assume the point $x=(0,0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{A}^n$ lies on multiple components, all of codimension 1; by Hauptidealsatz these components are (possibly after passing to a smaller open subset) cut out by single equations. Hence we need to check if that $f,g$ vanish at $x$, then the hypersurface $V(fg)$ is not smooth at $x$; indeed all of the partials take the form $f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)=0$ (slightly abusing notation here).

So the conclusion is that $W$ can only have one component, hence it is an irreducible variety.